# Prove the inequality $\sum_{k=1}^{2n-1}\sqrt{k(4n-k)}<\pi n^2$ for all natural $n$

Tags: inequality

Prove the inequality $\sum_{k=1}^{2n-1}\sqrt{k(4n-k)}<\pi n^2$ for all natural $n$.

Please help me, I don't have an idea how to solve this.

Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried using an integral?  What happens if you complete the square for $\sqrt{k(4n-k)}$?

Comment: Have you considered proving it by induction?

Comment: @Adriano - the presence of the $n$ under the radix means that induction isn't trivial.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, we can rewrite L.H.S of the inequality we want to prove as
$$\begin{align}
\sum_{k=1}^{2n-1}\sqrt{k(4n - k)}
= & \sum_{k=1}^{2n-1}\sqrt{(2n)^2-(2n-k)^2} =\sum_{k=1}^{2n-1}\sqrt{(2n)^2-k^2}\\
= & 2n\sum_{k=1}^{2n-1}\sqrt{1-(k/2n)^2}\tag{*}
\end{align}$$
Second, notice for $\displaystyle x \in \left[\frac{k-1}{2n},\frac{k}{2n}\right)$, we have $\displaystyle \sqrt{1-x^2} > \sqrt{1-(k/2n)^2}$, this implies:
$$\int_{\frac{k-1}{2n}}^{\frac{k}{2n}} \sqrt{1-x^2} dx > \frac{1}{2n}\sqrt{1-(k/2n)^2}$$
Sum this up from $k = 1$ to $2n - 1$ and substitute this back into $(*)$, we get
$$
\sum_{k=1}^{2n-1}\sqrt{k(4n - k)} < (2n)^2 \int_0^{1-\frac{1}{2n}}\sqrt{1-x^2}dx
< (2n)^2 \int_0^1\sqrt{1-x^2}dx = \pi n^2
$$